# PySPark - Function to determine the dtype after an operation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

While using `udf` in PySpark we have to declare the return type of the operation while creating the `udf`.

Now consider a scenario where I have two columns and I'm adding them to get a third column. I add them up using the following

```
>>> udf_add  = udf(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], IntegerType())
>>> spark.createDataFrame([(101, 1, 16)], ['ID', 'A', 'B']).withColumn('Result', udf_add(array('A', 'B'))).show()
+---+---+---+------+
| ID|  A|  B|Result|
+---+---+---+------+
|101|  1| 16|    17|
+---+---+---+------+
```

Now assume that one of the columns is instead a float and I perform the same operation

```
>>> spark.createDataFrame([(101, 1, 16.1)], ['ID', 'A', 'B']).withColumn('Result', udf_add(array('A', 'B'))).show()

+---+---+----+------+
| ID|  A|   B|Result|
+---+---+----+------+
|101|  1|16.1|  null|
+---+---+----+------+
```

In this case, I get a null because my result is actually a float but I had mentioned to the `udf` that its gonna be a float. To overcome this, I change my `udf` to be of `FloatType` to account for all cases

```
>>> udf_add = udf(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], FloatType())
```

But when I pass integer values to it, it returns `null` value.

```
>>> spark.createDataFrame([(101, 1, 16)], ['ID', 'A', 'B']).withColumn('Result', udf_add(array('A', 'B'))).show()

+---+---+---+------+
| ID|  A|  B|Result|
+---+---+---+------+
|101|  1| 16|  null|
+---+---+---+------+
```

So the question is - is there a data type in pyspark that is inclusive of integer and floats and can handle both the cases above?

If not, is there a way to determine or not define the data type before hand?

The reason I'm asking this is because I have multiple datasets and I want to perform the same set of operations across them. The values can be integers or floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a data type in pyspark that is inclusive of integer and floats and can handle both the cases above?

There is not. If you want your code to be as generic as possible cast output to the most generic type that can accommodate results:

```
 udf(lambda x: float(x[0] + x[1]), DoubleType())
```

or ensure that correct types are always used on call by casting input columns.

```
 udf(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], DoubleType()) 
 ...
 udf_add(array('A', 'B').cast("array<double>")
```

Obviously you'd never use `udf` for simple addition in a production code. Just use `__add__` (`+`) on `Column` objects. We use `udf` only when more efficient solution is not possible.

> If not, is there a way to determine or not define the data type before hand?

No. Return type has to be known beforehand and `udf` is a black box - Spark has no way to tell what should be the types.